# Servicestack conflicting routes?

Tags: rest, routes, servicestack

I have the following request objects:

```
[Route("/Model/Blah/BySlug/{Slug}/", "GET")]
[Route("/Model/Blah/ByBlahSeriesId/{SomeOtherId}/", "GET")]
[Route("/Model/Blah/ById/{Id}/", "GET")]
public class GetBlahRequest : Blah, IReturn<BlahResponse>
{
    public int Start { get; set; }
    public int Limit { get; set; }

}

[Route("/Model/Blah/", "POST")]
public class PostBlahRequest : Blah, IReturn<BlahResponse>
{

}

[Route("/Model/Blah/", "PUT")]
public class PutBlahRequest : Blah, IReturn<BlahResponse>
{

}
```

And I'm being told there are conflicting routes on the GET?

How can that be? they are very different. The code to call the get is:

```
 var blahResult = _client.Get(new GetBlahRequest
            {
                Id = model.BlahId
            });
```

Am I missing something here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You do have a conflict. Because your `GetBlahRequest` DTO when extended with `Blah` would be the equivalent to:

```cs
public class GetBlahRequest
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public int BlahSeriesId { get; set; }
    public string Slug { get; set; }
    public int Start { get; set; }
    public int Limit { get; set; }
}
```

When the client tries to make a request say with `{ Id = 123 }` it can't know which of the 3 routes to choose from. If `BlahSeriesId` is not nullable (`int?`) then it defaults to `0`, `Slug` will default to `null` but will be treated as empty. It effectively sees these three routes:

```
/Model/Blah/BySlug//
/Model/Blah/ByBlahSeriesId/0/
/Model/Blah/ById/123/
```

While in this scenario, it's obvious it should choose the last route, the client is really warning of scenarios where you may specify a `Slug` and an `Id`, which according to your DTO is perfectly valid, and thinks aargh!

```
GetBlahRequest
{
    Id = 123,
    Slug = "Something"
}
```

Would result in three possible routes of:

```
/Model/Blah/BySlug/Something/
/Model/Blah/ByBlahSeriesId/0/
/Model/Blah/ById/123/
```

While it's a little more work, the routes should be separated to DTOs with clearer intent.

```cs
public class GetBlahRequest : Blah
{
    public int Start { get; set; }
    public int Limit { get; set; }
}

[Route("/Model/Blah/ById/{Id}/", "GET")]
public class GetBlahById : GetBlahRequest, IReturn<BlahResponse>
{
}

[Route("/Model/Blah/BySlug/{Slug}/", "GET")]
public class GetBlahBySlug : GetBlahRequest, IReturn<BlahResponse>
{
}

[Route("/Model/Blah/BySeriesId/{BlahSeriesId}/", "GET")]
public class GetBlahBySeriesId : GetBlahRequest, IReturn<BlahResponse>
{
}
```

Then in your action methods:

```cs
public BlahResponse Get(GetBlahById request)
{
    return GetBlah(request);
}

public BlahResponse Get(GetBlahBySlug request)
{
    return GetBlah(request);
}

public BlahResponse Get(GetBlahBySeriesId request)
{
    return GetBlah(request);
}

BlahResponse GetBlah(GetBlahRequest request)
{
    // Code to return BlahResponse
    return ...
}
```

Then your client needs to call:

```cs
var blahResult = _client.Get(new GetBlahById { Id = model.BlahId });
```

Comment: Ahaaaa OK that kinda makes sense! Scott you're a legend - I'll take a look tonight. I guess I made a lax assumption on something. The OCD part of me likes having them all separate as you suggest anyway :)